# How do we calculate the directional derivative of a vector field? (If there is such a thing.)

Tags: derivatives, field-theory, vector-analysis, vector-fields

So, for a scalar field $T(x,y,z)$, the derivative along $d\vec l$ is given by $$\frac {dT}{|d\vec l|} = |\vec \nabla T| \cos\theta$$where $\theta$ is the angle between  $\vec \nabla T$ and $d\vec l$

For a vector field $\vec V (x,y,z)$, I understand that $\vec \nabla . \vec V$ and $\vec \nabla \times \vec V$ give the **Divergence** and the **Curl** respectively.

But, is there a way in which $\vec \nabla$ can act on $\vec V$ to give an expression for $\frac {d \vec V}{|d\vec l|}$, the directional derivative of $\vec V$ along $d\vec l$?

PS: I've only just started to learn vector calculus, so pardon me if this question comes out as silly.

Comment: What _static_ means here?

Comment: When I say _static_, I mean that the field remains constant with time. @enzotib

Comment: So, given that time does not appear anywhere, it is not useful, and misleading, to talk at all of time variable, and to use the word _static_.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! @enzotib

Comment: It is not a silly question. I will summarize. To take directional derivatives of vector fields, you need the notion of a connection. Given a Riemannian metric $g$ on your smooth manifold, you then have a notion of directional derivative using the associated Levi-Civita connection.

Comment: A more elementary answer is as follows. A vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be thought of as a triple of smooth real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the components of the vector field). You can define the directional derivative of such a vector field to be the triple of directional derivatives of its components. However, in order to define the directional derivative of a vector field on a possibly "curved" space, by which I mean a smooth manifold, you need the notion of a connection. In other words, there is no canonical way to define such a notion on a general smooth manifold.

Answer (score 1):

The nabla operator is not the correct tool for vector fields. In this case, it is better to recognize that the gradient $\nabla T$ is just a special case of the total differential $\mathrm DT$, which is just the Jacobian of $T$. The directional derivative in $x_0$ in direction $v$ is then

$$\mathrm DT(x_0)\cdot e_v,$$

where $e_v$ is the unit vector in $v$-direction. This will be a vector, since the Jacobian $\mathrm DT$ is a matrix, but this is expected, since $T$ is vector valued. Going back to the special case of a scalar field, where $\mathrm DT=\nabla T$, this becomes

$$\mathrm DT\cdot e_v=\nabla T\cdot e_v=\vert\nabla T\vert\vert e_v\vert\cos\theta=\vert\nabla T\vert\cos\theta,$$

which is exactly what you started with.

Comment: The question was about the directional derivative of a vector field

Comment: @enzotib: Thanks for the heads up. Should be better now.

Comment: I arrived at $\frac {dT}{|d\vec l|} = |\vec \nabla T| \cos\theta$ from the expression: $dT=\frac {\partial T}{\partial x} dx +\frac {\partial T}{\partial y} dy+\frac {\partial T}{\partial z} dz$, which I believe is the total differential.

I wrote the same equation as $dT=\biggr{(}\frac {\partial T}{\partial x} e_{x} +\frac {\partial T}{\partial y}  e_{y}+\frac {\partial T}{\partial z}  e_{z}\biggr{)}.(dx\space e_x+dy\space e_y+dz\space e_z)$ where $e_x,e_y,e_z$ are the unit vectors in the x,y,z directions respectively. This is the same as  $dT=\vec \nabla T.d\vec l$

Comment: How do I do the same for a vector field?

Comment: If you really have to use coordinates, you should at least use index notation, because otherwise it will be atrocious to read. Then you can write $\mathrm dT_j=\mathrm dx_i\partial_i T_j=\mathrm JT\cdot\mathrm d\vec l$, where $\mathrm JT=(\partial_i T_j)_{ij}$ is the Jacobian. So $\frac{\mathrm d\vec T}{\vert\mathrm d\vec l\vert}=\mathrm JT\cdot \vec e_l$ with $\vec e_l$ the unit vector in direction $\vec l$.